# Put list of links in correspond to img tags in a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I have here a simple `string` containing `<img>` tags & a `list` of example links:

```
s  = '''

<img src =''>
Is python a slow programming language because it's an interpreted one? :D

<img src =''>

I love python! but some say it's slow... Time to switch to Go or Julia?
<img src =''>

<img src =''>

'''

links = [
"https://www.google.com",
"https://www.facebook.com",
"https://www.twitter.com",
"https://www.youtube.com",
]
```

Now the main goal here is to put those links in **correspond** to those `img` tags. Something like this would be the output:

```
<img src ='https://www.google.com'>
Is python a slow programming language because it's an interpreted one? :D

<img src ='https://www.facebook.com'>

I love python! but some say it's slow... Time to switch to Go or Julia?
<img src ='https://www.twitter.com'>

<img src ='https://www.youtube.com'>
```

### Solutions I searched for & tried

1.) Converting `s` into a bs4 object but to be honest I must not convert it to a bs4 object but I tried. I did what I searched about [replace_with](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) with bs4 & I get that output. The links were there right? but somehow it's not a proper `img` tag & the output now becomes a **PURE** `html` code, I just want it to be the same `content` as variable `s` but the links inserted or see provided sample output.

So using `bs4` would not be really relevant but I'd be open to it. But for me to be honest, I would not want to have it converted to another `object`.

```
s  = '''

<img src =''>
Is python a slow programming language because it's an interpreted one? :D

<img src =''>

I love python! but some say it's slow... Time to switch to Go or Julia?
<img src =''>

<img src =''>

'''

links = [
"https://www.google.com",
"https://www.facebook.com",
"https://www.twitter.com",
"https://www.youtube.com",
]

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html5lib')
imgs = soup.find_all("img")

#I could use zip() but let's take it this way
for idx,img in enumerate(imgs):
    img.replace_with(f'<img src="{links[idx]}"">')


print(soup)
```

**Output:**

```
<html><head></head><body>&lt;img src="https://www.google.com""&gt;
Is python a slow programming language because it's an interpreted one? :D

&lt;img src="https://www.facebook.com""&gt;

I love python! but some say it's slow... Time to switch to Go or Julia?
&lt;img src="https://www.twitter.com""&gt;

&lt;img src="https://www.youtube.com""&gt;

</body></html>
```

2.) Using the `.split()` method of `str` object won't work cause there would be times that the `img` tag would not have a space gap with the sentence or word, so it would be useless.

3.) I've come to think about the best way to do this is with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) with the sample code solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726308/how-to-replace-the-img-tag-using-python-without-beautifulsoup), however the only issue I am having is that this would only replace **ONE** `img` tag though it's a great solution! I learned & realised a lot from it. Also if regular expressions would be the best solution, I am having trouble implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to have placeholder and let python do the replcement for you if possible:

```
links = [
"https://www.google.com",
"https://www.facebook.com",
"https://www.twitter.com",
"https://www.youtube.com",
]

s  = '''

<img src ='{}'>
Is python a slow programming language because it's an interpreted one? :D

<img src ='{}'>

I love python! but some say it's slow... Time to switch to Go or Julia?
<img src ='{}'>

<img src ='{}'>

'''.format(*links)
```

Another way could be to use f-string (python3.6+):

```
google = "https://www.google.com",
facebook = "https://www.facebook.com",
twitter = "https://www.twitter.com",
youtube = "https://www.youtube.com",
]

s  = f'''

<img src ='{google}'>
Is python a slow programming language because it's an interpreted one? :D

<img src ='{facebook}'>

I love python! but some say it's slow... Time to switch to Go or Julia?
<img src ='{twitter}'>

<img src ='{youtube}'>

'''.format(*links)
```

Or use Jinja https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/ directly.

Comment: Woow! Why are you guys so good & fast at thinking solutions! The first one would be a great solution. Wow! I did not know about `*links` well to a function this `*` would mean that you can put many arguments and loop through it right... well because of your answer I am enlightened more to the use of `*` which means kinda like a variable that can be iterated.

Comment: The `placeholder` is a good idea tho but on my original string it doesn't have that, let me first change the string being generated to have a `placeholder` or `{}`.

Comment: And `**` does the same but for dict :-)

Comment: Hello! this is a far great alternative solution but I was thinking also if there could be a way without the place holders, cause what's keeping this possible is thanks to the `{}` right... I'd like to see if there could be other solutions & search more if not I think this would be okay :)

Comment: Then use beautiful soup, to output stuff you can use `soup.prettify()` like in the doc: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I've mentioned about the about being generated that it returns a pure html, & I think that's what not the output I was hoping for...

Comment: Hello I'm accepting this answer :) As I made the `{}` as `placeholders` also people keep downvoting it , of course it's stackoverflow! Thanks a lot!